# Cant access object via variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object defined as follows:

```
var tabs = {
    'nav_tweet_search':'tweet-panel',
    'nav_shopping_cart':'cart-panel',
    'nav_stats':'stats-panel'
};
```

Im trying to access some values using a variable in another function. However, i am getting `undefined`. I created some console logs ..

```
console.log("panel: "+panel);
console.log("tabs: "+tabs);
console.log("tabs.panel: "+tabs.panel);
```

Which outputs,

```
panel: nav_tweet_search 
tabs: [object Object] 
tabs.panel: undefined
```

Any reason why i wouldnt be able to access the obj using a variable? If i do "tabs.nav_tweet_search" it works

Comment: Can you show some more of your code? I believe you have some other code that creates a variable called `panel`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
console.log("tabs[panel]: " + tabs[panel]);
```

When you do `tabs.panel` the browser will look for a property called "panel", but only "nav_tweet_search", "nav_shopping_cart" and "nav_stats" are defined.

When using brackets the value of the variable will be used as the key for fetching the object property. If you use `tabs.panel` that's equivalent to `tabs["panel"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want

```
tabs[panel]
```

This gives the property with name `panel` of `tabs`.